# Checking PHP Syntax via Web Page

Tags: php, syntax

I've used "php -l" many times while on the command line to check whether a file contains valid PHP, but I've struggled to perform this task from a web page.

```
$out = `php -l /path/to/my.php`;
// or...
$out = `php -d error_reporting=1 -l /path/to/my.php`;
// or...
$out = `php -d error_reporting=1 -l /path/to/my.php 2>&1`;
print $out;
```

But nothing seems to return a value that I can test.  I've tried using exec and shell but nothing seems to return a value when it's called this way; the same code works fine when PHP is called in CLI mode.

(For the record, authorized users are supplying these files, and I am sanitizing the file input, and in this situation the check has to be done via a web page).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your first example works fine for me. I created a test file that was accessed via the web using your first example, and it output `No syntax errors detected in test11.php`. Not sure why this wouldn't be working in your case.

Comment: @Fred: Not exactly. The backticks mean to execute the string and then return the output, similar to `exec()`.

Comment: @Fred see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($out)` ?

Comment: @NickCoons Thanks Nick. I deleted my comment, soon as I caught on after I noticed the `-l` etc. My mistake. Another "tick" on my "gaining a wee bit more experience belt". ;-)

Comment: @Mike Thank you Mike. Had I seen a `shell` or `exec` tag, I would have known right away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a web output you need to work with ".php" files and doing something like this.

```
<?php 
    $res=`php -l /var/www/html/fagace/index.php`;
    print ("<html>
      <head>
        <title>An example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <strong>$res</strong>
      </body>
   </html>"); 
?>
```